# How set more than one paths has to be added to the PATH environment variable and other variable?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bash-profile

I am adding commands to `$HOME/.bash_profile` file

```
export PATH=[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin:$PATH

export ANDROID_HOME=/home/harsh/SDK

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

Now I have to run  `source $HOME/.bash_profile` when my system boot every time. Is there any other option to permanent set these paths?

Problem: It's annoying to run this commands again and again when my system boot. Is there a way when I start my system and don't need to add this commands again?

Comment: Bash should read `~/.bash_profile` on startup if it's started as a login shell, so it's not really just "a file". Now, the question is, how do you start Bash, if the login shell startup files don't take effect? In what sort of an environment?

Comment: What is the file *actually* called, and which shell are you using? You are hopefully aware that various filenames on UNIX-ish systems are "magic" so it really does make a difference.

Comment: So I have to move that commands to .bashrc ? and link to .bash_login

Comment: Please just edit your question to explain: 1) what you're trying to achieve 2) precisely what you've tried so far (not hiding details like which filename) 3) what's happening. Stop making random guesses as to what you should do until you've explained the issue or we can't really help.

Answer (score -2):

You have to add entries to ".bashrc" file to create persistent environment variables for a user. [Please see this for the detailed explanation.](https://www.electronproton.com/setting-up-persistent-environment-variables-in-linux/)

Comment: Using `.bash_profile` should work too, provided that 1) the shell is a login shell, or 2) `.bash_profile` is sourced by `.bashrc`.  In fact, I'd argue that `.bash_profile` is the correct place for setting up one's environment, while `.bashrc` is for things specifically related to interactive shell sessions (such as setting one's prompt, displaying a calendar or uptime etc.).

Comment: This is at best misleading and at worst actively wrong. There are plenty more config files than `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/profile`.